# How can I leave just the Numbers?

Tags: replace, split, strip

Okay so the below string outputs `<span id='current_health'>453</span>` to the console.

```
var c_health = document.getElementById("current_health");
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to remove the HTML bits and leave just the number. Here is what I tried...

```
var c_health = document.getElementById("current_health");
c_health = c_health.replace("<span id='current_health'>",'');
c_health = c_health.replace("</span>",'');
```

But nothing echo's to the console. I am very new to JS. So any help would be appreciated.

My end game goal is to be able to read the number and based on whatever number is in that HTML block change a css variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will give you the `<span>` [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which does not provide a replace method.

If you want to get the value 453 from the `<span>` you don't have to use replacements but you could get it from the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property:

```js
var c_health = document.getElementById("current_health");
console.log(c_health.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span id='current_health'>453</span>
```